# How can I share a variable across multiple activities? (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, variables, android-activity, data-sharing

I'm trying to share a variable across multiple activities, and all I've been able to find out until now is how to move it from one activity to the next activity (by clicking on a button you go to the next activity and the variable gets carried over). But when trying to repeat this process to one screen further, I keep getting the default value of 0 printed out. Why is this happening?

The code below shows the corresponding code inside of the first of three activities. So here when I click on the button to go to the next activity all these variables get carried over to the next activity. But when I repeat this code on the next activity it doesn't work.

```
   val welcomeButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.welcomeButton)
            welcomeButton.setOnClickListener {
                val userHeight = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.et_UserHeight).text.toString().toInt()
                val userWeight = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.et_UserWeight).text.toString().toInt()
                val userAge = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.et_UserAge).text.toString().toInt()
                val userGender = findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.genderSpinner).toString()
                val userActivityLevel = findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.activityLevelSpinner).toString()
                val userWeightGoal = findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.weightGoalSpinner).toString()
                val intent = Intent(this, WelcomeActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("EXTRA_AGE", userAge)
                intent.putExtra("EXTRA_HEIGHT", userHeight)
                intent.putExtra("EXTRA_WEIGHT", userWeight)
                intent.putExtra("EXTRA_GENDER", userGender)
                intent.putExtra("EXTRA_ACTIVITYLEVEL", userActivityLevel)
                intent.putExtra("EXTRA_WEIGHTGOAL", userWeightGoal)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
```

The code below is the second activity where I am trying to send the variables over to a third activity. But I am unable to use the variables on the third activity. Any thoughts on why?

```
    val userAge = intent.getIntExtra("EXTRA_AGE", 0)
            val userHeight = intent.getIntExtra("EXTRA_HEIGHT", 0)
            val userWeight = intent.getIntExtra("EXTRA_WEIGHT", 0)
            val userGender = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_GENDER")
            val userActivityLevel = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_ACTIVITYLEVEL")
            var userWeightGoal = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_WEIGHTGOAL")


            val welcomeToHomeButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.SendToHomeButton)
            welcomeToHomeButton.setOnClickListener {
                intent.putExtra("EXTRA_AGE", userAge)
                intent.putExtra("EXTRA_HEIGHT", userHeight)
                intent.putExtra("EXTRA_WEIGHT", userWeight)
                val intent = Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Every activity has a [getIntent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#getIntent()) method (translated to just `intent` in kotlin), that returns the intent, that started that Activity.

In your code below, you first set the extras to the intent of the second activity, and then create a new intent that starts the third activity:

```
welcomeToHomeButton.setOnClickListener {
   intent.putExtra("EXTRA_AGE", userAge)
   intent.putExtra("EXTRA_HEIGHT", userHeight)
   intent.putExtra("EXTRA_WEIGHT", userWeight)
   val intent = Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java)
   startActivity(intent)
}
```

You need to create a new Intent first, and then set extras to it, like this:

```
welcomeToHomeButton.setOnClickListener {
   val intent = Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java)
   intent.putExtra("EXTRA_AGE", userAge)
   intent.putExtra("EXTRA_HEIGHT", userHeight)
   intent.putExtra("EXTRA_WEIGHT", userWeight)
   startActivity(intent)
}
```